# How do I achieve a "floating container" in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I want a "floating container" to apear at the bottom of the screen. Any ideas how do I pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a container to be displayed "over top" of everything else at the bottom of the screen, you can use the `Form.getLayeredPane()` method to get a layered pane that is rendered over the form.  If you place a `BorderLayout` container there and place your "floating container" in the south, it will effectively appear at the bottom of the screen.

E.g.

```
Container layeredPane = theForm.getLayeredPane(MyClass.class, true);
layeredPane.add(BorderLayout.south(myFloatingContainer));
```

[Javadocs for getLayeredPane()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Form.html#getLayeredPane-java.lang.Class-boolean-)